# Apache says certificate not valid for 192.168.0.44, but it is valid for 192.168.0.44

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, web-server

I am having trouble creating an SSL certificate for a website that is served by Apache.  When I visit `https://192.168.0.44` via FireFox, I get the error message:

```
Websites prove their identity via certificates. Firefox does not trust this site because it uses a certificate that is not valid for 192.168.0.44. The certificate is only valid for 192.168.0.44.
 
Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN
```

Here are the steps to reproduce the issue.

Requirements:

- One computer with Ubuntu OS on the ip address `192.168.0.44`.
- One computer with Windows on any `192.168.0.*` address.

Steps:

I go to the Ubuntu machine.

I run this command:

```
mkdir -p /etc/certs/test;
```

I create the file `/etc/certs/test/entity.cnf` with the following content:

```
[req]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
x509_extensions = v3_req
prompt = no
[req_distinguished_name]
C = CA
ST = ON
L = Windsor
O = Ankle
OU = Hello
CN = 192.168.0.44
[v3_req]
keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, keyAgreement
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = 192.168.0.44
```

I make a file called `/etc/certs/test/make-certs.sh` with the following content.

```
#!/bin/bash

ORG="ABTEST"
CN="abtest"
certdir="/etc/certs/test"

mkdir -p $certdir;
cd $certdir;

## Create certificate authority
openssl genrsa -out $certdir/ca.key 2048
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -key $certdir"/ca.key" -subj "/C=CA/ST=ON/O="$ORG"/CN="$CN -days 3650 -out $certdir"/ca.crt"

## Create entity certificate

# Private Key
openssl genrsa -out $certdir/entity.key 2048
# CSR
openssl req -new -sha256 -nodes -key $certdir"/entity.key" -config $certdir"/entity.cnf" -out $certdir"/entity.csr"
# Certificate
openssl x509 -req -in $certdir"/entity.csr" -CA $certdir"/ca.crt" -CAkey $certdir"/ca.key" -CAcreateserial -out $certdir"/entity.crt" -days 500 -sha256 -extensions v3_req -extfile $certdir"/entity.cnf"
```

I run the command:

```
./make-certs.sh
```

I install Apache2 with this command.

```
apt-get install -y apache2;
```

I create a `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf` with this content:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost _default_:443>
                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

                DocumentRoot /var/www/html
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
                SSLEngine on
                SSLCertificateFile      /etc/certs/test/entity.crt
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/certs/test/entity.key
                SSLCACertificateFile /etc/certs/test/ca.crt
                <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>
        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I run these commands:

```
a2enmod ssl;
a2ensite default-ssl.conf;
systemctl restart apache2;
```

I run this command:

```
cat /etc/certs/test/ca.crt
```

I copy the output.

I go to the Windows computer.

I paste the clipboard content to a txt file called `ca.crt`.

I go to FireFox Settings and import `ca.crt` as a certificate authority.

I visit `https://192.168.0.44` with FireFox.

I see the error message mentioned at the beginning of this question.

---

However, I will not get this error if I repeat the steps above but change just 3 things:

- On my Ubuntu machine, I replace all instances of `192.168.0.44` with `hello.test.com` in the `/etc/certs/test/entity.cnf`
- On my Windows computer, I add the line `192.168.0.44 hello.test.com` to the file `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`.
- On my Windows computer, I visit `https://hello.test.com` with FireFox web browser.

With these 3 changes, FireFox shows a green lock icon and says everything about my SSL certificate is perfect.

How do I fix my situation so that `192.168.0.44` can use a verifiable and trusted certificate?

---

Additional Note:

This is what FireFox says when I visit `https://192.168.0.44` when the Apache uses a cert for `192.168.0.44`
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your alt names is incorrect. It should be

```
[ alt_names ]
IP.1 = your_ip_address
```

By the way a certificate is never created for an ip adress and will never be trusted.
You can create a certificate based on a domain name which links using dns to an ip.

Comment: Your solution actually worked!  So can you clarify why it will never be trusted?  Because FireFox seems to trust the certificate of `192.168.0.44`.

Comment: Because you create an entry in the host file for the ip, it's nasty. You made it trusted on your own device, but when you visit from another client it won't be trusted. The whole internet works by using DNS, translating an ip to a domain name, and a certificate is usually checked up the dns name. If you have for example 1000s of requests to your site, it's way more easy to update the dns in one place, then having to reconfigure the cert on 1000 places

Comment: @Turdie You will be surprised when you visit https://1.1.1.1/

Comment: @AlexD That's the exception then. But it's issued by a CA which is already trusted Digicert

Comment: @Turdie No, it is not an exception. Why do you think there is even an IP type for subject alternative names defined? And the talk about creating entries in the host file to make something trusted and reconfiguring a cert in 1000 places doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Im not going into this nifty picking discussion. In general it's best practice to issue certificates based on domain name / fqdn